# Find x such that $\sqrt {x-6} = x\sqrt{x-6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all real values of $x$ such that

$$\sqrt {x-6} = x\sqrt{x-6}$$

I got $x = -6$ and $x = 1$, but how can that be because both of these values of $x$ give a negative under the radical.

Comment: Working with the real numbers only, the only solution would be $x = 6$, since $\sqrt{1-6}$ would be undefined. Working with complex numbers, $\sqrt{1-6} = 5 i$ is defined and $x = 1$ is the other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can cancel the sqrt factor unless it is zero. Also $x\geqslant6$

Answer (score 2):

Working in the reals,

$x\sqrt{x-6} - \sqrt{x-6} = 0$

$(x-1)(\sqrt{x-6}) = 0$

By the Zero-product property

$x - 1 = 0, \sqrt{x-6} = 0$

$x = 1, x = 6$

But $x \geq 6$ since the square root cannot be negative, so $x = 6$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is of type $y=zy$, that is, multiplying by $z$ does not change $y$, then $y$ better be zero. In this case $y=\sqrt{x-6}$, so $x=6$.